How to make a dynamic range out of a list in Excel?
A fairly common problem I have in excel is that I import a large set of data and want to do various calculations on it. But first I have to "fill down" my data rows, like such:

But if the input data is a dynamic array, I don't need to do that!  Automatically I can define a dynamic array function and it fills to the bottom and no further.

So my question is how do I make that initial input into a dynamic array?  If the data in column A were unique, I can, say, make a dynamic range in column B with =UNIQUE(A:A).
But if the data is not unique, I cannot seem to do =A:A without it filling column B to the bottom of the sheet, i.e. row 1048576, which makes the sheet explode in size (and computation time).
What I want is something like =A:to_the_last_datapoint_in_A_and_no_further
Is there such a thing?
Thanks!
/YGA

Perhaps you could try something like this using the help of LastRow


=LET(
     _Data, A:A,
     _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/(_Data<>"")),
     UNIQUE(A2:INDEX(_Data,_LastRow)))



Using LET() function makes easier to read as well reduces the use of redundant calculations, also improves efficiency.
_Data is a defined variable for the range A:A
_LastRow is a defined variable for getting the last use row in the range A:A which used MATCH() function to return the position.
Anchoring the first known cell that is A2 with INDEX() function to create a reference range to return the data till the last row.
Finally applied UNIQUE() - if any required.


Or Using TOCOL()
=UNIQUE(DROP(TOCOL(A:A,1),1))



Using TOCOL() function excluding the single array with empty rows as the 2nd param defines that.
Using DROP() function excluding the header as we have the taken the whole range that is A:A
Lastly, wrapping within UNIQUE() function as applied if any required.


Or Another cleaner approach will be to use Structured References aka Tables and then use it in the formula, so as Tables help takes the data till the last row as well auto resizes with add or remove in data.


=UNIQUE(SomeData[Header])


NOTE: The UNIQUE() function is redundant here, one can exclude that as well if required. Used the same function thought OP needed unique as well.


This is excellent.  I think that I the best formula is: =LAMBDA(range,LET(max_index,MATCH(2,1/(range<>"")),TAKE(range,max_index,1)))(A:A)
But now my next question - what if I don't want to select a single column but want to do over a bigger range?
In other words - that MAX_INDEX -- can we do it (a) over a 2d array, and (b) have a separate calculation for MAX_COL and MAX_ROW?

For avoidance of doubt: I don't want to do "UNIQUE" - that's merely an example of a version of this that works.  But it only works if the inputs are unique, which they are not!

@YGA yes you can do it. Can you show one example. Banking on the first method you can do it, provided we have to take one column as a base range.

Also UNIQUE() is not needed as you have mentioned, it is just to return the unique values without it also the above should work. For MAX_COL i will be using AGGREGATE() function. Something like this : =AGGREGATE(14,7,COLUMN($1:$1)/($1:$1<>""),1) or may be like this =TAKE(TOROW(COLUMN(1:1)/(1:1<>""),2),,-1)

See: https://superuser.com/questions/1838013/how-to-make-a-dynamic-range-out-of-a-2d-array-in-excel

One Note: if there is no unique, then the UNIQUE() function is redundant, you can exclude it.

@YGA so do you want the output in Column C, can you please reply?

No - I want a column which is the exact same as column A but is a dynamic array, so that when I have formulas that reference it they reference the dynamic array version.
In some sense this question is analogous to "how do I automatically make a structured table?"

@YGA dont you think the solutions posted above shows exact same as Column A

Oh it's perfect!

@YGA you dont follow solutions correctly, TOCOL() was simpler and will be quicker. Do take time to read the whole post. Which I have already posted since you are not familiar with Excel formulas looks like you have not used the one proposed here already. Anyways.

Ah.  Yes, you are right - TOCOL(A:A,1) is exactly what I was looking for.

I think https://superuser.com/users/1247873/mayukh-bhattacharya's response is excellent, and in fact what I was looking for was very simple:
=TOCOL(A:A,1)

And what about
=FILTER(A:A, A:A<>"", "Empty")

Remove empty cells, does not remove duplicates.

Updated with "Empty".

super intuitive and simple, though it doesn't generalize to more than one column.
