How to make a dynamic range out of a 2D array in Excel?
This is the 2D version of How to make a dynamic range out of a list in Excel?.
Imagine I have a 2D array of data. I'd like to generate a dynamic array out of it so that formulas that use it automatically resize as data is added to the bottom.
I could create "structured tables" out of it but that is an extra step that feels unnecessary.  What I really want is a lambda that runs over the whole sheet and creates a dynamic array that other formulas can run off of.
Sort of a 2-D version of this:

But I want it to be:

(This is sort analogous to asking "how can I use dynamic arrays to automatically generate a structured table?").

Mayukh's answer works below, but I think this is a little simpler:
=LAMBDA(range,TAKE(range,MATCH(2,1/(CHOOSECOLS(range,1)<>""),1)))
Use as such, though note that it will only read off the number of rows of the first columns - if other columns have more rows it won't work.


Updated as per new edit, explanations are already given in the last post of OP, previous question:


=LAMBDA(array,
  LET(
      _Data, array,
      _LastRow, MATCH(2,1/(TAKE(_Data,,1)<>"")),
      _Output, TAKE(array,_LastRow),
      IF(_Output=0,"",_Output)))(E:F)

For First Question: Answers Explained Here

Edit:
Considering both the columns, and not taking only the first column as base then the following should work as well:


=LAMBDA(array,
 LET(
     _Data, TAKE(array,AGGREGATE(14,7,ROW(array)/(array<>""),1)),
     IF(_Data="","",_Data)))(E:F)



No - I'm so sorry for the unclarity! Updated the question.
